# Docker compose apt command doesn't run

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, certbot

I have this part in my docker-compose.yaml:

```
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    volumes:
      - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
      command: apt-get update && apt-get install python-certbot-nginx
```

Otherwise certbot does not start the cert creation. When I run docker-compose up, the other containers in the file run correctly, but the certbot container fails with this error:

```
certbot_1   | Certbot can obtain and install HTTPS/TLS/SSL certificates.  By default,
certbot_1   | it will attempt to use a webserver both for obtaining and installing the
certbot_1   | certificate.
certbot_1   | certbot: error: unrecognized arguments: apt-get update && apt-get python-certbot-nginx
base_1      |
chatwoot_certbot_1 exited with code 2
```

Note that the install is missing from the second command. If I change anything else (like remove the apt-get update) the change is reflected in the error log, but the commands never run.

Tried using Dockerfile to RUN the command, the docker-compose.yaml relevant part looks like this:

```
  certbot:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
```

And the Dockerfile:

```
FROM certbot/certbot
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-certbot-nginx
```

The error is now this:

```
Building certbot
Step 1/2 : FROM certbot/certbot
 ---> 0091bcdbf8c6
Step 2/2 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-certbot-nginx
 ---> Running in 64119cd99255
/bin/sh: apt-get: not found
ERROR: Service 'certbot' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-certbot-nginx' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The base image isn't necessarily Debian-based (it may not use APT as a package manager), and it may have an entrypoint that interprets the `command:` as something other than a shell command.  If you do need to install additional packages, doing it in the Dockerfile is almost always better than trying to do it at startup time.

Comment: What OS is the base image of your docker container using?  If it's RHEL or adjacent (Centos, Fedora, for example) you may need to use yum or dnf, respectively.  On top of that, there's no guarantee that the package is named the same across package mangers.  Another thing worth looking into is making your own Dockerfile to create a container based on the certbot, and including the apt/apt-get/yum/dnf/eopkg/yadayada step as part of the build process, rather than updating and installing on each startup.